# Scale an image with CSS while keeping rounded corners

Tags: html, css, background-image, image

Can anyone help please?

I have a image that I am displaying on my page. The image has some rounded corners which I have achieved with some CSS trickery. But the problem is now to auto scale the image.

Scaling the image with a `<img>` is no problem, but using it in for the rounded corners code I have becomes a problem because this is achieved with background-image.

Does anyone know how I can combine the 2?

Here is how I achieve the rounded corners in CSS:

```
.informationBarLeft {
width: 24%;
height: 160px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
float: left;
margin-right: 1%;
background-image: url('../Images/pumpkin-soup.jpg'); /*The image to use */
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
```

}

And the HTML is then simply:

```
<div class="informationBarLeft">&nbsp;</div>
```

As you can see I dont use the `<img>` element anywhere, so Im wondering can this be done in CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use css3 [**background size property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) to scale `background-size: 100% 100%;`

```
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;           
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;           
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;      
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `background-size: cover;`:

```
.informationBarLeft {
  width: 24%;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1%;
  background-image: url('../Images/pumpkin-soup.jpg'); /*The image to use*/
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/ZbTVh/)

Comment: It's better to have an empty div than a dull &nbsp; !

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any problems while scaling the image using `background-image: url("#")`. Check this out here: http://jsfiddle.net/sE3RG/

I think you just need to remove the comment `/* The image to use` or at least close it with an ending */ tag

[OR] you can use the `background-size: cover;` code, but I haven't seen it work many a time. Works on the JSFiddle code though :)

Comment: Oops no that comment was added when I had the code sample posted here. Its not actually part of my code, but seems that the background-size: cover; is going to work for me. Thanks